# Getting values from Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need help in fetching values from a response object in an ajax call

Code Snippet

```
$.each(responseJson.slice(0,7), function (index) {
var resp_JSON=responseJson[index];
console.log(resp_JSON);
```

In console the `resp_JSON` is `Object {17130003: "A message string from the cache"}`

Now the response Json doesn't has a name tag so that I can do `resp_JSON.id` or something & get the value. It just has values.

I tried

`resp_JSON[0];`  //Error

`resp_JSON.Object[0];` //Error

I need to fetch `17130003` & `A message string from the cache` in two separate javascript variables.

Comment: Actually you need to access `resp_JSON['17130003']`, if the keys are dynamic you can use `Object.values(resp_JSON)` and `Object.keys(resp_JSON)`

Comment: @HassanImam Thanks buddy it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the **keys** and **values** of the object. You can do this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(resp_JSON); // [17130003]
var values = Object.values(resp_JSON); // ["A message string from the cache"]
```

Note that both are arrays, and you can simply loop through the array to handle each value/key.

Also, as @Hassan has pointed out, you can get the specific value by `resp_JSON['some_key']` if that's what you want to achieve.